# Update textarea model in Emberjs

Tags: ember.js, data-binding, components

I have a component which contains a switch and a yielded form. 
The switch changes the model used for the yielded form. 
In the said form, I have a textarea whose value comes from the model. When I update the model in the component, the textarea is bent to the correct model but the value inside it doesn't update. I can't figure out how to do it

I'm using Ember 1.13.

Here is my component:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

const { computed } = Ember;

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  // Properties
  switchField: null,
  defaultModel: null,
  specificModel: null,

  activeModel: computed('switchField', 'defaultModel', 'specificModel', function() {
    if (this.get('switchField')) {
      return this.get('defaultModel');
    } else {
      return this.get('specificModel');
    }
  }),

  editDisabled: computed('switchField', function() {
    if (this.get('switchField')) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }),

  renderSwitch: function() {
    Ember.run.schedule('afterRender', this, function() {
      $('.toggle-switch').bootstrapToggle();
    });
  }.on('init'),

  actions: {
    reflectChange: function(value) {
      this.set('switchField', value);
      this.rerender();
    }
  }
});
```

The template:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <input data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" class="toggle-switch" type="checkbox" checked={{switchField}} onchange={{action "reflectChange" value="target.checked"}} />
  <br>
  <br>
</div>

{{ yield activeModel editDisabled }}
```

And how it is used:

```
{{#inherit-switch switchField=warehouse.companyInheritance.inheritCarrierProcedure defaultModel=company specificModel=warehouse as |activeModel editDisabled|}}
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    {{#form-group value=activeModel.errors.carrierProcedure }}
      <label class="control-label" for="carrierProcedure">Procédure coursier</label>
      {{textarea class="form-control" id="carrierProcedure" value=activeModel.carrierProcedure disabled=editDisabled}}
    {{/form-group}}
  </div>
{{/inherit-switch}}
```

I tried to `rerender` the component but it doesn't work.
I don't understand why the value doesn't change since the textarea gets correctly enabled/disabled when I toggle the switch.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not really sure what's going on - but I tried to put together a little example / maybe it will help - but it's pretty naive: https://ember-twiddle.com/155af741d2c1896a2d6a5e4ae0804c3f?numColumns=2&openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2Ctemplates.application.hbs